# Can not check if input has value or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop through array of ids and check if value exists or not and do stuff code below:

```
function checkBillingFields() {

var inputIDS = [ "#billing_first_name", "#billing_last_name", "#billing_company", "#billing_phone", "#billing_address_1", "#billing_address_2", "#billing_city", "#billing_city"];

var arrayLength = inputIDS.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    console.log(inputIDS[i]);

    if ($("inputIDS[i]").val().length == 0){

        $('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper').appendTo('.billing-fields');

        $(".billing-heading").css({'margin-top': '100px'});

    }else{
        $(".expand-billing").css({'display': 'none'});
    }

}

}

checkBillingFields();
```

I get error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I use local storage to store inputs and it works fine tested.

Any ideas are helpful as I been researching and trying to fix that but nothing worked.

Comment: try with `$(inputIDS[i])`, problem is that you are looking for an element like `inputIDS[i]` and ofc no element like this exist

Comment: You don’t need to use `.length`, you could just check for `$("inputIDS[i]").val()`; if the value is an empty string, the expression will evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your if statement with

```
if ($(inputIDS[i]).val().length == 0)
```

This will use jQuery directly with value from array and not with string literal as used in your case.

To really make sure you don't get any errors anymore, do it like this

```
//First check if element actually exists in DOM
var tmp = $(inputIDS[i]);
if (tmp.length == 1 && tmp.val().length == 0) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like your `console.log()` use the same in your `if` statement

```
console.log(inputIDS[i]); 
if ($(inputIDS[i]).val().length == 0){
```

`inputIDS[i]` // returns #billing_first_name if i = 0 
`"inputIDS[i]"` would return `"inputIDS[i]"`

Comment: @Z3K No problem, happy to help